# os.path AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'exists'

Tags: python

I'm trying to reproduce the code from this site: https://www.guru99.com/python-copy-file.html

The general idea is to copy a file using python. Although I can work my way around the errors, I also **want to understand what I'm doing wrong** in this case.

```
import shutil
from os import path
def main(filename):
    if path.exists(filename):
        src = path.realpath(filename)
        head, tail = path.split(src)
        dst = src + ".bak"
        shutil.copy(src,dst)

main('C:\\Users\\test.txt') #This raises the error
main('test.txt') #This works, if the file is in the same folder as the py script
```

If used with the full directory (main('C:\Users\test.txt')) The code returns the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'exists'`. If I remove the line with `path.exists()` I get a similar error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'realpath'`.
By using the filename `main('test.txt')` everything works, as long as the file is in the same folder as the python script that contains the function.

So I tried reading the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html), which states for both `path.exists()` and `path.realpath()`:

> Changed in version 3.6: Accepts a path-like object.

Since **I'm running 3.7.1** I went foward to check what is a "path-like object":

> An object representing a file system path. A path-like object is either a str or bytes object representing a path, or an object implementing the os.PathLike protocol. An object that supports the os.PathLike protocol can be converted to a str or bytes file system path by calling the os.fspath() function; os.fsdecode() and os.fsencode() can be used to guarantee a str or bytes result instead, respectively. Introduced by PEP 519.

From that, given that I provided a string, I take it should be working. So what I'm missing?

Comment: That doesn't sound like it has anything to do with what string you're passing in. That sounds like you named the argument `path` in one version of your code and completely forgot about it.

Comment: @user2357112 Agreed. Since the code here is fine, voting to close as a problem that can't be reproduced.

Comment: Try `print(type(path))` just ahead of the first use.  I expect that will produce `str` rather than a `path` object.  If so, you need to trace the definition of `path` back to its source.  Your posted code does not show this problem.

Comment: Same problem here. I tried print(type(path)) and I get the error "name path is not defined".
I changed all path variable names to target, and I still have this error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code:

```
import shutil
from os import path
def main(filename):
    if path.exists(filename):
        src = path.realpath(filename)
        head, tail = path.split(src)
        dst = src + ".bak"
        shutil.copy(src,dst)

main('C:\\Users\\test.txt') #This raises the error
main('test.txt') #This works, if the file is in the same folder as the py script
```

It works fine, but if you re-define a local variable named path, like this:

```
import shutil
from os import path


def main(filename):
    if path.exists(filename):
        src = path.realpath(filename)
        head, tail = path.split(src)
        dst = src + ".bak"
        shutil.copy(src, dst)

# The path variable here overrides the path in the main function.
path = 'abc'  

main('C:\\Users\\test.txt')  # This raises the error
```

**This is just your code I guess, obviously this is a wrong example.**

I would recommend using the `os.path` after `import os`, because the path variable name is very common, it is easy to conflict.

For a good example:

```
import shutil
import os


def main(filename):
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        src = os.path.realpath(filename)
        head, tail = os.path.split(src)
        dst = src + ".bak"
        shutil.copy(src, dst)

main('C:\\Users\\test.txt')
main('test.txt')
```

Comment: is this an answer or are you showing what *not* to do?  because shadowing a name you just imported is a horrible idea.

Comment: @Corey Goldberg  I am showing the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Type on shell

```py
Type(path)
```

And check result and value, maybe you redefine this import to a variable str.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\test.txt')
```

that actually works for me... i dont if it works for you